# Different inside v home page in custom Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to use a different header style for the home page than for inside pages of my site. Specifically, I want the header section to be less tall on the inside pages.  Should I use a different header.php file for the home page? If so, how?

I'm having a hard time getting ideas using Google, so if anyone has a helpful link to the appropriate resource that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a home page boolean function `is_front_page()` (true if is front page otherwise false)

Add a class to the header/body/whatever parent so

```
<header class="header<?php if(is_front_page()){ ?> home_header<?php } ?>">
</header>
```

and simply reference the class in CSS.

[WordPress codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Comment: Thank you! I'm having a browse through the list of Wordpress functions now, there's a lot of useful stuff in there.